# How to set a fixed size imageView embedded in the fragment?

Tags: android, imageview

I made a listfragment to show the imageview embedded in another fragment.
By choosing the items of the list, different images with different resolution will be shown.
But I want to make them to be shown as the same size.So this is what I did.
But with different images and resolutions, they are shown in different sizes.

```xml
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
</ImageView>
```

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment android:name="com.example.showdognames.DogImageFragment"
    android:id="@+id/DogImageFragment"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <fragment android:name="com.example.showdognames.DognameFragment"
    android:id="@+id/DognameFragment"
    android:layout_weight="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

```java
public class DogImageFragment extends Fragment {

    Integer[] imageList = new Integer[] { R.drawable.alaskan_malamute,
            R.drawable.beagle, R.drawable.border_terrier, R.drawable.dashshund,
            R.drawable.finnish_spitz, R.drawable.greyhound,
            R.drawable.portuguese_water_dog, R.drawable.rottweiler };

    private ImageView myView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dog_image_fragment,
                container, false);
        myView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200));
        return myView;
    }

    // method setImageResource is used to bound image reference array and
    // imageView
    public void update(int position) {
        if (myView != null) {
            myView.setImageResource(imageList[position]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:layout_weight="wrap_content"
```

Seriously?

If the problem is the ImageView that not shows the image at the desired width and height you can set the android:scaleType of imageview try with fitCenter or fitXY. and see what you want to show.